# I get a white line right in every section in UITableView with section headerview

Tags: swift, uikit

This is how the UITableView with section header currently looks like:
[image: Example of the unwanted space]

How can this unwanted white space be removed?

I have configured a `headerView` for each section.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let headerView = UIView()
    .....
    return headerView
}
```

Comment: I think this extra spacing was added in iOS 15. There’s a table view property you can use to set it to zero but you still might see the last cell’s divider just above the next section’s header. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/3750914-sectionheadertoppadding

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```
if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
    tableView.sectionHeaderTopPadding = 0
}
```